# How to make 'onItemDisclosure' arrow for a list appear in the middle of the item (vertically)

Tags: sencha-touch

Setting on onItemDisclosure to true in the configuration options for my list makes the arrow appear but it is at the top of the list rather than at the middle. If the list items were of a fixed height I could add margin to put it lower down but because each item of the list can vary in height this won't be suitable.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this css rule `.x-list .x-list-disclosure` add `position: relative;
top: 28%;` or any percent you want. You can add this inline in the index.html after the main css file.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why specifying 50% seems to move it more than 50% from the top of the item in the list?  I've set it to 35% and it's dead in the middle. So it gives the desired result but I am just wondering why it's 35% and not 50%.

Comment: It sets the top corner of the arrow to be at 50% of the list item height. The 15% off are so the arrow (31px in height) be centered. So you can't always exactly center it. But if you have list items with similar heights from 50px up 100px, 35% or less is good enough since you can't notice 1 or 2 px difference. If you want a pixel perfect center than you must set it dynamically via JavaScript, i.e. take the height of each list item - 31 (for the arrow) and divide it by 2 to get the exact top in px.

Comment: If satisfied with the answer please mark it as correct answer to close this question.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. And don't worry I always choose an answer if I am helped, but it can take me a day since I am at work.

Answer (score 0):

Use following for the parent item css and will work best ever:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
```

This is webkit specific and works perfectly with Sencha Touch. So, the code will be:

```
.x-list .x-list-item{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get true centering:

```
.x-list .x-list-disclosure {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-mask-position-y: center;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```